# XDM display manager builds but does not run

Tags: raspbian, xorg, login

I'm trying to modify the X display manager (xdm) source code in order to use it for a special purpose. However when I build and install it, it does not run and I end up getting the non-X login prompt. It does not print anything to the logs either. Is there anything special that I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

The display manager that runs by default on Raspbian is `lightdm`, and it is started by [`init`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init).  For wheezy's SysV style init, this is via `/etc/init.d/lightdm`, which is linked into the various `/etc/rc[N].d` directories.  To undo that, use `sudo update-rc.d disable lightdm 2 3 4 5`.  Raspbian jessie switched to `systemd` for init, and I'm not sure what the name of the lightdm service is there, but you could find it with `systemctl list-units | grep -i lightdm`.  If it's not there, it might be using a backward compatible mechanism, so look in the `rc.d` directories and try the `update-rc.d` method.

To start `xdm`, you'll have to add your own init script/service.  At least for testing purposes though, you can probably stick it in the end of `/etc/rc.local`.